# Rearranging Expression to a Standard Form for Transfer Function

Tags: python, sympy

I'm a newcomer to Python/Sympy and I'm hoping it can make life easier understanding control system topics.  A common requirement for me is to cross-check equations developed in the literature against my own derivations.  When it comes to transfer functions, the denominator is typically ordered with the higher orders of s on the left, with order decreasing moving to the right.  The highest order s term has a unity coefficient.

Here's an example (taken from [here](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/TF2ZPK.html)):

[image]

I've developed my own transfer function using sympy and I'd like to rearrange it in the fashion just described.

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import simplify
from IPython.display import display

s, tau_1, tau_2 = sp.symbols('s,tau_1,tau_2')
F = (1+s*tau_2)/(1+s*(tau_1+tau_2));

k_0, k_d, N = sp.symbols('k_0,k_d,N')
H = (k_0*k_d*F)/(s+((k_0*k_d*F/N)))

display(H.simplify())
```

Which yields:

[image]

Now, I'm not really expecting simplify to know which format I'd like the expression displayed, but I'm hoping there's an existing function or set of functions that will help me to arrange it the way I'd like.  Is there?

**FURTHER UPDATE:**

After a bit of manipulation, I've managed to isolate the highest power and divide across by the coefficient top & bottom to leave the highest order term without a coefficient, as I wanted.  It's not perfect by any stretch.  An improvement would be to have each term stand alone and ordered highest to lowest as with most polynomial presentations.  I notice that collect() doesn't order the power terms as you'd expect.  What's that all about!?

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import simplify
from sympy import poly
from sympy import degree
from IPython.display import display

s, tau_1, tau_2 = sp.symbols('s,tau_1,tau_2')
F = (1+s*tau_2)/(1+s*(tau_1+tau_2));
display(F)

k_0, k_d, N = sp.symbols('k_0,k_d,N')
H = (k_0*k_d*F)/(s+((k_0*k_d*F/N)))
display(H)

def normTF(expr):
    H_c = expr.ratsimp().collect(s)
    n,d=sp.fraction(H_c)
    collected = sp.Poly(d, s).as_expr()
    degree = sp.degree(collected, gen=s)
    terms = dict(i.as_independent(s)[::-1] for i in sp.Add.make_args(collected))
    sn=(n/terms[s**degree]).ratsimp().collect(s)
    sd=(d/terms[s**degree]).ratsimp().collect(s)
    return sn/sd

display(normTF(H))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
In [30]: H.cancel().collect(s)
Out[30]: 
           N⋅k₀⋅k_d⋅s⋅τ₂ + N⋅k₀⋅k_d          
─────────────────────────────────────────────
          2                                  
k₀⋅k_d + s ⋅(N⋅τ₁ + N⋅τ₂) + s⋅(N + k₀⋅k_d⋅τ₂)
```

EDIT:

Here is a more involved answer:

```
In [44]: n, d = H.cancel().as_numer_denom()

In [45]: n = Poly(n, s)

In [46]: d = Poly(d, s)

In [47]: n
Out[47]: Poly(N*k_0*k_d*tau_2*s + N*k_0*k_d, s, domain='ZZ[N,k_0,k_d,tau_2]')

In [48]: d
Out[48]: Poly((N*tau_1 + N*tau_2)*s**2 + (N + k_0*k_d*tau_2)*s + k_0*k_d, s, domain='ZZ[N,k_0,k_d,tau_1,tau_2]')

In [49]: pre = cancel(n.LC()/d.LC())

In [50]: pre
Out[50]: 
k₀⋅k_d⋅τ₂
─────────
 τ₁ + τ₂ 

In [51]: n = n.monic()

In [52]: d = d.monic()

In [53]: Mul(pre, n/d, evaluate=False)
Out[53]: 
                             1                
                         s + ──               
k₀⋅k_d⋅τ₂                    τ₂               
─────────⋅────────────────────────────────────
 τ₁ + τ₂   2     k₀⋅k_d      s⋅(N + k₀⋅k_d⋅τ₂)
          s  + ─────────── + ─────────────────
               N⋅τ₁ + N⋅τ₂      N⋅τ₁ + N⋅τ₂
```

This seems to be almost what you want except that the terms in the denominator are not in the order that you expected.

It is possible to write more code to control the order of Add/Mul when converting from Poly to Expr but that is more involved.

Comment: It's close! And thanks for responding, by the way.  I've been working away trying to learn this stuff all day and I came to exactly the same solution.  But, now I'm trying to take it further.  Let me update.  If I can figure out the max order of s, then I can use the coefficient to divide top and bottom.  My inexperience is slowing me up!

Answer (score 0):

Z-Domain Example (not question asked but related)

In the z-domain it is usual to have the coefficients collected as negative powers of z, rather than positive powers of s (as normal is s-domain). EG:

```py
b0, b1, b2, a0, a1, a2, z = symbols('b0, b1, b2, a0, a1, a2, z')
hz = ((b0 + b1 * z**(-1) + b2 * z**(-2)) / (a0 + a1 * z**(-1) + a2 * z**(-2)))
hz
```

[image]

The required form!

Any manipulation takes expression out of required form, e.g. simplify.

```py
hz_s = hz.simplify()
hz_s
```

[image]

cancel().collect(z) doesn't work! Does nothing.

Have to do it manually ☹️.

```py
hz_n, hz_d = fraction(hz_s)
(hz_n / z**2).simplify() / (hz_d / z**2).simplify()
```

[image]